# Need Solution regarding assembly program: output and integer max number output

Tags: assembly, integer, output, factorial

i am writing assembly program counting factorial. And i got two questions.

1. Why the max number output can be up to 255? How can I fix it?
2. How can I make automatic output, to console, instead of writing "echo $?".

here is code:

```
SYSCALL = 0X80
STDIN = 0
STDOUT = 1
SYSREAD = 3
SYSWRITE = 4
SYSEXIT = 1

.section .data

NUMBER = 5

.section .text
.globl _start

_start:

pushl $NUMBER
call factorial
addl $4, %esp
movl %eax, %ebx


mov $SYSEXIT, %eax
int $SYSCALL


.type factorial, @function

factorial:

pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl 8(%ebp), %eax
cmpl $1, %eax
jle end_factorial

decl %eax
pushl %eax
call silnia
movl 8(%ebp), %ebx
imull %ebx, %eax

end_factorial:
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

Comment: You need to make a local variable area on the stack so that you can convert a number to a string. Read up on stack frames.

Answer (score 1):

You write to STDOUT by:

```
movl    4, %eax          ;sys_write
movl    1, ebx           ;stdout
movl    $buffer, %ecx     ;pointer to buffer to write
mov     10, %edx         ;length of buffer to write
int     0x80
```

Max exit code range is 0 to 255, 255 == 11111111b. (8 bits, 1 byte, AL part of EAX register)

You have to convert your binary number in EBX into an ASCII string (the ASCII chars would go inside of "buffer" which would be defined as 10bytes of data, initialized to 0x20 (ASCII space) for simplicity.

Comment: @sadasfsdafas fgasgasd - you have to define one, or you could use the stack.